# Can't get options with $data['variable']

Tags: php, wordpress, variables

**Can't get options with $data['variable'].**

*(I'm using SMOF - Slightly Modded Options Framework)*

For example in the header.php (index.php, footer.php, etc.):

```
global $data;
$logo_type = stripslashes( $data['type_logo'] );
```

and nothing happens, variable `$logo_type` contains nothing.

But if I use the same code in the \css\styles.php - all works fine.

First encountered this problem... And can not understand what could be the problem (php, web hosting, etc.)

Anyone else encountered this problem?

Comment: turn on errors `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: what is `var_dump($data);` saying?

Comment: `error_reporting` if turning on. `var_dump($data);` return `NULL`

Answer (score 1):

You mention that this is not working in the header.php file. This could be caused by the variable $data not being declared before the header.php file is invoked.

Have you checked that $data has been defined prior to trying to access data from that variable?

Comment: It defined. For example, in the file functions.php I can get data from  variable $data. But not from header.php, index.php, footer.php, etc.

Comment: From what I have been able to extract from the SMOF and WordPress documentation, $data is set by the function and the values are retrieved using `get_option(<option>, <default>)`. The value of $data is not defined before then.

Comment: Call the function `get_option` to retrieve values from the options set by WordPress.

Comment: This function already calls in the framework file \admin\functions\functions.admin.php, also trying to call this function `$data = get_option(OPTIONS);` — no luck

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you add this code in header.php before add your current code

```
global $data;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
global $smof_data;

$logo_type = stripslashes( $smof_data['type_logo'] );
```